# "(click)" event not triggered when clicking on a material icon

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I've created a `<a>` tag which is also provided with a `(click)` event function call.

The click works everywhere, even for all the child elements, except on the following arrows mat-icons (see code below for a full view):

```
<span *ngIf="section.pages.length>0">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="section.id==id_focus">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="section.id!=id_focus">keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
</span>
```

What am I doing wrong in all of this?

> **MY CODE:**

```
      <a mat-list-item class="text-light listitem" (click)="switchSub(section.id)" (mouseenter)="expandSub(section.id)">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2">

          <!--CLICK NOT WORKING FROM HERE...-->
            <span *ngIf="section.pages.length>0">
              <mat-icon *ngIf="section.id==id_focus">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon *ngIf="section.id!=id_focus">keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
            </span>
          <!--...TO HERE-->

            <ng-container *ngIf="section.pages.length<=0">
              &nbsp;
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span><mat-icon>{{section.icon}}</mat-icon></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-7">
            <span *ngIf="isExpanded"> &nbsp; {{section.name}} </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
```

> **PAGE VIEW**

[image: CLICK FOR PAGE VIEW]

Where `(click)` is not working on blue square, which is the material icon mentioned above. Everywhere else, it works. 
 The blue square is correctly poisitioned inside the parent box.

Comment: Have you checked in DOM whether these elements are rendering or not?

Comment: Also check the `z-index` of those icons

Comment: Hi @PardeepJain! Yes, I confirm you that the elements are correctly rendered in the DOM

Comment: @PardeepJain I've edited the z-index with three values: -1000, 0 and 1000 but nothing changed on the page behavior

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on stackblitz? it would be easier to sort out there

Comment: @PardeepJain On [my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j633r5) the click event works fine, but I'm not able to make material icons work. The difference is that here I've removed the mouseover event for simplicity. So I tried to remove it even on my project, but nothing changed

Comment: @PardeepJain Got it! The issue seems to be related on the use of `*ngIf` **inside** the mat-icon tag. IDK if it's an angular material bug or if it's something wanted. Moving the ngIf of the  mat-icon tag on a father ng-container solved the issue

Comment: Great, Glad to know you sort out yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be related on the use of `*ngIf` **inside** the `mat-icon` tag. IDK if it's an angular material bug or if it's something wanted.

By the way, **moving the `*ngIf` of the `mat-icon` tag on a father `ng-container`** solved the issue.

My final working code:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let section of myRoutes">
    <ng-container *ngIf="section.name!='null'">

      <a mat-list-item class="text-light listitem" (click)="switchSub(section.id)" (mouseenter)="expandSub(section.id)">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2">

          <!--ADDED ng-container AND REMOVED ngIf from the mat-icon tag-->
            <span *ngIf="section.pages.length>0">
            <ng-container *ngIf="section.id==id_focus">
              <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="section.id!=id_focus">
              <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
            </ng-container>
            </span>
          <!---------------------------------------------->

            <ng-container *ngIf="section.pages.length<=0">
              &nbsp;
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span><mat-icon>{{section.icon}}</mat-icon></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-7">
            <span *ngIf="isExpanded"> &nbsp; {{section.name}} </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Does it work without the material icon directive?

I had a weird issue today with a `mat-icon-button`.

The material styling was present when I added the `mat-icon-button` directive (so I knew for sure the module was included) but the `(click)` event just wouldn't work. Removing the `mat-icon-button` directive **would** make it work.

So I had an array of buttons that was driven by a template property:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let breakpoint of breakpoints">

     <button mat-icon-button
             (click)="toggleVisibility(breakpoint)">
         <mat-icon [class.selected]="breakpoint.selected">{{ breakpoint.icon }}</mat-icon>
     </button>

 </ng-container>
```

In the template `get breakpoints() { ... }` would return the same items each time.

However, what must have been happening (roughly) is that the mouse-down triggered a change detection cycle and then the button didn't exist anymore when Angular tried to run its `(click)` handler. This wasn't happening with the native buttons.

For me the fix was setting change detection to `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. Making sure the `breakpoints` property was returning the same array instance would probably have fixed it too.

To be honest the most surprising thing was I've never come across this particular issue before. If you get this - your solution may vary but understanding the issue is the most important starting point.